Swagger UI OpenAPI 3 issue - Requestbody parameter with required as true isn't rendering well
I am using OpenAPI 3.0 and whenever I am trying to use required: true with requestBody, the request body is not rendering well as you see in following screenshot.

This is my YAML:

The YAML I attached above I tried and I was wondering to load all parameters in requestbody but it's simply showing string on UI.

Please post the full requestBody node from your YAML file (in case the screenshot has collapsed content). If the requestBody includes $refs, please post those referenced schemas too.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please post the StudentRequest schema too.

Can you provide more context on the schema? IF you add something similar I believe it should fix your issue
requestBody:
  required: true  # Indicates that this request body is mandatory
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          yourCustomProperties: 
            type: object
            additionalProperties: {}

With that told, if you share your yml code it will be more helpful.

Please refer the comment that I added
